# PHP Number Format with a calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I am still relatively new at this so I am sorry if this seems like an easy fix, I am doing a calculation and I want the answer to present 2 numbers after the decimal. Right now it is giving me the results above my table and not replacing the numbers in the table.

http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/cnghlgoalieinfo.php?GoalieID=71

This is what I currently have set up

```
    Print "<tr>";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Sea']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Team']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['GP']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Min']."</center></td> ";
$iGAA = $row['GA'] * 60 / $row['Min'];
Print $english_format_number = number_format($iGAA, 2);
Print "<td><center>".$iGAA."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['W']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['L']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['OTL']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['T']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['SO']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['GA']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['SA']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['PCT']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['PIM']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Assists']."</center></td> ";
```

}

Could you please show me how to fix it, so I can get the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the wrong variable:

```
Print "<td><center>".$english_format_number."</center></td> ";
```